# How do I automatically add time to a datetime field in django models?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a Django Model with a `start_datetime` and a `end_datetime`. It all works fine, except for the fact that when I save data into the model, it saves it as `2017-04-19 00:00:00` and `2017-04-29 00:00:00`. I want to be able to save it as `2017-04-19 00:00:00` and `2017-04-19 23:59:59` automatically, without having to take user input for time again.

My models:

```
class ProductNotes(models.Model):
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField('Start Date', null=True, blank=True)
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField('End Date', null=True, blank=True)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#datefield

Answer (score 1):

Well, i think that your question has many alternatives, but the most directly solution to your requirement is save current time at the moment that user execute the action,

try some as:

```
import datetime

def some_view(request):
    # some view actions
    product_notes_objet.end_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
```

In other way, maybe you could be interested in a field that automaticaly update by itself every time that you update your object, so as:

`updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`

**EDIT**

If you want to save the current date at 23:59:59 you can do some as follow:

```
# getting current date with format mm/dd/YYYY
current_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now().date(), "%m/%d/%Y")

# creating a datetime from curret date at the time 23:59:59
current_date_at_235959 = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_date+" 23:59:59", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

# saving the datetime created
product_notes_objet.end_datetime = current_date_at_235959
product_notes_objet.save()
```

Maybe other way could be overwrite your `save` method to your model or work with signals

Comment: I don't want it to save with the time right now, I want it to save as 23:59:59.